# Cannot query in gdrive .Children.list

Tags: google-drive-api

I set

```
String queryString2 = "mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.folder' and  title='333213' ";                 
Children.List request_2 = service.children().list(mainFolder_Id);
request_2.setQ(queryString2);
```

But the result cannot be filtered by `queryString2`. It just returns all the items in the folder. What's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [documentation](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/drive/v2/java/latest/com/google/api/services/drive/Drive.Files.List.html#setQ%28java.lang.String%29). `setQ` returns `Drive.Children.List` with proper `q` set.
Your code should look like this:

```
String queryString = "mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.folder' and  title='333213' ";                 
Children.List request = service.children().list(mainFolder_Id).setQ(queryString2);
ChildrenList children = request.execute()
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Should be working now. There was a regression that temporarily broke queries with children.list but it has since been fixed.