# gdrive .Children.list cannot query in JAVA and JAVASCRIPT

Tags: google-drive-api

I  set

```
String queryString2 = "mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.folder' and  title='333213' ";

Children.List request_2 = service.children().list(mainFolder_Id);
request_2.setQ(queryString2);
```

I  test  in  javascript  API here  also doesn't work.

> https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/children/list

the  result  cannot   filtered  by the  queryString2.  It  just  response  all the  items in folder. 
Anyone  know  what's wrong???

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cannot query in gdrive .Children.list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18117662/cannot-query-in-gdrive-children-list)

Comment: You asked same question an hour ago. The only difference is that it doesn't work for js too. Please add these additional info as comment in your original question.

Comment: Hey,  I  still get  500 Error  : W/System.err(2152):   "message": "Internal Error". Do you  means  google's  Api  Error??

Comment: Could you print error stack trace?

Answer (score 0):

Should be working now. There was a regression that temporarily broke queries with children.list but it has since been fixed.